# Does $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x_1^2}{x_1+x_2}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x_1^2}{x_1+x_2}, &\text{ if }x_1+x_2\neq 0\\
0, & \text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases}$$
Does $\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)$ exist?
I tried several sequences and it seems that the limit $=0$, but I haven't found a good way to prove it using $\varepsilon-\delta$.

Comment: What happens if you use the curve $x_2=x_1^2$?

Comment: And then ask what happens if you use $x_1 = 0$.

Comment: No need for an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof. Just throw back to Calc 3.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Why does that help? For small $x_1$, the numerator is $x_1^2$ and the denominator approx $x_1$, so it tends to 0.

Comment: @almagest: No, the denominator then is $x_1+x_1^2$ and the fraction tends to $1$.

Comment: @Mathematician42 For small $x_1$, $x_1$ is much bigger than $x_1^2$.

Comment: @almagest: Crap, you are right, brainfart Sunday I guess. Luckily Salahamam_Fatima's answer fixes the extra $x_1$.

Comment: @Bernard I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_{1,n}=1/\sqrt{n}$, and $x_{2,n}=1/n^2-x_{1,n}$. Then $(x_{1,n},x_{2,n})\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. But $f(x_{1,n},x_{2,n})=n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

- for $x_1=0\implies \frac{x_1^2}{x_1+x_2}\to 0$
- for $x_1=t \quad x_2=-t+t^2\implies \frac{x_1^2}{x_1+x_2}= \frac{t^2}{t-t+t^2} \to 1$

Comment: I guess you mean $x_2=x_1^2$?

Comment: Yes of course!!!

Comment: Nevermind, I'm having brainfarts too today (see the comments and Salahamam_Fatima's answer).

Comment: Thanks for the comprension and to have pointed out my fault.

Comment: It was wrong again, now it should be ok! :)

Comment: Yes, I made the same mistake (taking limits too $\infty$ in my head I guess!) That's why I referred you to the comments, but I should specified which comments I meant :)

Answer (score 1):

With $x_2=\lambda x_1^2-x_1$, it becomes

$$\lim_{x_1\to 0}\frac {x_1^2}{\lambda x_1^2}=\frac {1}{\lambda} $$

from here, the limit does not exist.